# How to write Dagger component in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, dagger-2

I am new to dagger and kotlin language, I want to translate the below java code into kotlin code.This is the Dagger component written in Java.

```
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, NetworkingModule.class})
    public interface ApplicationComponent {
       public PresentationComponent newPresentationComponent(PresentationModule presentationModule);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be like this,

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class, NetworkingModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun newPresentationComponent(PresentationModule presentationModule): PresentationComponent
}
```